# VueJS error on IE11 - SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer, babeljs, vue-cli

**IE11 - ERROR: SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'**

Hi! My website works on every browser except IE. My babel.config.js file:

```
 module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@vue/app', {
      polyfills: [
        'es.promise',
        'es.symbol',
        'es6.array.iterator'
      ]
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    [
      'component',
      {
        libraryName: 'element-ui',
        styleLibraryName: 'theme-chalk'
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

---> [Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OipFj.png)

---> [Debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o20FH.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your debugger screenshot shows the error is from the `native-toast` package.  That package's GitHub shows an [unresolved issue](https://github.com/egoist/native-toast/issues/9), in which a `for ... of` loop is used.  IE does not know how to interpret it, which is a common cause of the Vue IE SCRIPT1004 error (which is just a missing semicolon).

You can tell Vue CLI to transpile the entire `native-toast` dependency package, which is something it does not do by default.  In your `vue.config.js` (not Babel):

```js
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'native-toast'  
  ]
}
```

(Note: `transpileDependencies` is an array of package names [or RegExp])

Apparently, in some cases you may also need this in your `babel.config.js` (try without it first):

```js
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    '@babel/preset-env'
  ],
}
```

Reference:

[Vue CLI `transpileDependencies`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#transpiledependencies)

[Vue CLI polyfills guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#polyfills)

[Vue Forum `transpileDependencies` example](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/transpiledependencies-problem/43851/7)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to transpile 'vue-stripe-checkout' as well. ^_^

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked :)  Did you have to alter the Babel config or was `transpileDependencies` enough?

Comment: **transpileDependencies** was enough =D